# I need to figure out what exactly the function of the % sign in C

Tags: c

when you write code such as
printf("Average score: %f\n", (score[0] + score[1] + score[2]) / 3.0);

what is the point of the %f , is it needed?, i know that sometimes you change the letter after it, what are ways you can use the %?

Comment: `%f` here is a placeholder for printing your `(score[0] + score[1] + score[2]) / 3.0` as a floating-point number, for example if it is `3.5` then it will print `Average score: 3.500000` followed by a new line

Comment: Spend an hour or so learning [man 3 printf](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html)

Comment: As you're trying to piece together the format string, I recommend these 2 reference pages, in this order: 1) https://cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/, and 2) https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf. As a general rule, I find cplusplus.com to be easy to read and understand, but missing a ton of modern documentation, and cppreference.com to be insanely hard to understand, like reading Latin when you don't know Latin, but thorough and much more complete. I use both, but these days am finding myself more on cppreference.com now that I have a good baseline knowledge.

Comment: And, to 'turn off' the magic of '%', you use two ("%%") to have one '%' appear in your output string...  `printf( "%d%%", 42 );` will deliver, for example: "42%"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that's a [print formatter](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_printf.htm). "f" is for floats (decimals). the % is used when you want to put a variable value in a printf statement. So % followed by a letter (f,d,c,s,p, etc) indicates the type.

Comment: ok this made a lot of sense, thank you, it was a simple misunderstanding, but it was really making it so I couldn't fully understand what I was writing which is annoying sometimes, so I appreciate the fast response!